# Recommended SQL Server table design for file import and processing

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, import, batch-processing

I have a scenario where files will be uploaded into a database table (dbo.FileImport) with each line of the file in a new row. Each row will contain the line data and the name of the file it came from. The file names are unique but may contain a few million lines. Multiple file's data may exist in the table at one time.

Each file is processed and the results are stored in a separate table. After processing the data related to the file, the data is deleted from the import table to keep the table from growing indefinitely.

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileImport] (
        [Id]             BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [FileName]       VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
        [LineData]      NVARCHAR (300) NOT NULL
    );
```

During the processing the data for the relevant file is loaded with the following query:

```
SELECT [LineData] FROM [dbo].[FileImport] WHERE [FileName] = @FileName
```

And then deleted with the following statement:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[FileImport] WHERE [FileName] = @FileName
```

My question is pertaining to the table design with regard to performance and longevity...

- Is it necessary to have the [Id] column if I never use it (I am concerned about running out of numbers in the Identity eventually too)?
- Should I add a PRIMARY KEY Constraint to the [Id] column?
- Should I have a CLUSTERED or NONCLUSTERED index for the [FileName] column?
- Should I be making use of NOLOCK whenever I query this table (it is updated very regularly)?
- Would there be concern of fragmentation with the continual adding and deleting of data to/from this table? If so, how should I handle this?

Any advice or thoughts would be much appreciated. Opinionated designs are welcome ;-)

---

**Update 2017-12-10**
I failed to mention that the lines of a file may not be unique. So please take this into account if this affects the recommendation.

An example script in the answer would be an added bonus! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary to have the [Id] column if I never use it (I am
>   concerned about running out of numbers in the Identity eventually
>   too)?

It is not necessary to have an unused column. This is not a relational table and will not be referenced by a foreign key so one could make the argument a primary key is unnecessary.

I would not be concerned about running out of 64-bit integer values. `bigint` can hold a positive value of up to 36,028,797,018,963,967. It would take centuries to run out of values if you load 1 billion rows a second.

> Should I add a PRIMARY KEY Constraint to the [Id] column?

I would create a composite clustered primary key on FileName and ID. That would provide an incremental value to facilitate retrieving rows in the order of insertion and the FileName leftmost key column would benefit your queries greatly.

> Should I have a CLUSTERED or NONCLUSTERED index for the [FileName]
>   column?

See above.

> Should I be making use of NOLOCK whenever I query this table (it is
>   updated very regularly)?

No. Assuming you query by FileName, only the rows requested will be touched with the suggested primary key.

> Would there be concern of fragmentation with the continual adding and
>   deleting of data to/from this table? If so, how should I handle this?

Incremental keys avoid fragmentation.

**EDIT:**

Here's the suggested DDL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FileImport (
      FileName VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
    , RecordNumber BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY
    , LineData NVARCHAR (300) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_FileImport PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(FileName, RecordNumber)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! One thing that I failed to mention is that the lines in a file may not be unique... does this mean that making the composite primary key is no longer an option?
This is what I am thinking the table script would be:

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileImport] (
        [FileName]       VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
        [LineData]      NVARCHAR (300) NOT NULL
    );

 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FileImport_FileName]
  ON [dbo].[FileImport]([FileName] ASC, [LineData]);

Could you add your recommended creation script to your answer?

Comment: I suggested a composite primary key on FileName and an `IDENTITY` column. That will allow duplicate LineData within a file (which is what I meant by not relational). I'll add the DDL script.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I read your first point as to remove the ID column and then interpreted your second point incorrectly. This is perfect. So, just confirming that with this structure the INSERT, SELECT, DELETE that will be going on for each file will not cause issues with the index where I need to rebuild the index regularly?

Comment: @MarkWhitfeld, correct, you don't need to rebuild the primary key index aggressively. Normal index maintenance should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough sketch how I would do it

```
CREATE TABLE [FileImport].[FileName] (
        [FileId]             BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [FileName]       VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL
    );
go

alter table [FileImport].[FileName]
add constraint pk_FileName primary key nonclustered (FileId)
go

create clustered index  cix_FileName on [FileImport].[FileName]([FileName])
go


CREATE TABLE [FileImport].[LineData] (
        [FileId]       VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
        [LineDataId]             BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [LineData]      NVARCHAR (300) NOT NULLL.
    constraint fk_LineData_FileName foreign key (FileId) references [FileImport].[FileName](FIleId)
    );

alter table [FileImport].[LineData]
add constraint pk_FileName primary key clustered (FileId, LineDataId)
go
```

This is with some normalization so you don't have to reference your full file name every time - you probably don't have to do (in case you prefer not to and just move FileName to second table instead of the FileId and cluster your index on (FileName, LeneDataId)) it but since we are using relational database ... 

 No need for any additional indexes - tables are sorted by the right keys

> Should I be making use of NOLOCK whenever I query this table (it is
>   updated very regularly)?

If your data means anything to you, don't use it, It's a matter in fact, if you have to use it - something really wrong with your DB architecture. The way it is indexed SQL Server will use Seek operation which is very fast.

> Would there be concern of fragmentation with the continual adding and
>   deleting of data to/from this table? If so, how should I handle this?

You can set up a [maintenance job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes) that rebuilds your indexes and run it nightly with Agent (or what ever)

Comment: My real production case actually separates the filename into a different table like you have done above, so Kudo's to you for the good real world design. I agree that having a FileId is much better than having the natural key of the filename. Thanks for your answer!